# How to open and read SQLite database from another platform like (iOS to Windows)

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, ios5, mfc

I am working on one `MFC` Application where I have to use `sqlite` database of `iOS` application.

The `iOS` database is encrypted by using `SQLite` API called `sqlite3_key()`.

But when I am trying to open the same database of `iOS` in my `MFC` Application it throws exception saying ***File is encrypted or not a database*** and unable to read the data from the database.

**The `iOS` database will be downloaded from `Dropbox` by `MFC` application and will replace current  database and use it instead of previous**

I am using following code for opening the database using [`CppSqlite3` Wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6343/CppSQLite-C-Wrapper-for-SQLite) for `Sqlite`:

```
    CppSQLite3DB db;
try{
    db.open("mydb.db");
    TRACE(_T("database opened"));
    db.key("1234", strlen("1234"));
}catch(CppSQLite3Exception e){
    return NULL;
}
```

As the `CppSQLite3DB` class does not have a function called `key()`. I have added that function in the class

```
   void CppSQLite3DB::key(const char* szKey, int nKey)
{
    if (mpDB)
    {
        sqlite3_key(mpDB, szKey, nKey);
    }
}
```

and upgrade my library to [SQLiteEncrypt](http://www.sqlite-encrypt.com/develop-guide.htm).
Whereas The `iOS` application is using [`SQLCipher`](http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial/) for `Database`.

But, the result is same. So,
Can anyone tell me how I can achieve that?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Are you sure that its correct to set the key after opening?

Comment: yes, Because the `iOS` database is encrypted with a key and to use it I have to set key to the database.

Comment: The [CppSQLite3DB](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=6343) class doesn't seem to have any method corresponding to `sqlite3_key()` (which is not the part of the [standard SQLite API](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html) anyways.)  I think you need an extended version of `sqlite3.lib` supporting encryption.

Comment: @nodakai I have edited my question explanation.

Comment: Then it's best to ask [the vendor](http://www.sqlite-encrypt.com/support.htm) since I could find no guarantee on portability across OS in their websie.

Comment: @nodakai i got some thing about `SQLiteEncrypt` library after reading its document. Actually it convert the key provided to the function to `AES 256` code. but I stuck on problem, which library should I use.  Can you please help me on that?

Comment: @AnkitB: ok, its just that in most other APIs that I know you have to set the key before opening the DB, so that the opening mechanism doesn't try to open the db as unencrypted.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I tried it too but it didn't worked.

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251113/c-how-to-reuse-encrypted-sqlite-database-in-mfc-application-which-is-already

Answer (score 1):

From http://sqlcipher.net/:

> SQLCipher has broad platform support for *[..]* [C/C++](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/) *[..]* [iPhone/iOS](http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial/) *[..]*

Perhaps using SQLCipher in your Windows application would solve incompatibility problems.